# Unable to delete Secrets from Key Vault with Soft-Delete enabled

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I created a Key Vault using PowerShell and enabled it for `Soft-Delete` and `Purge-Protection`. I then created some Secrets and pushed them into the new Key Vault. The default Access Policy that gets created when the Key Vault is created gives my account all permissions on Keys, Secrets, and Certificates except for `Purge`. As expected, when I tried to delete the Secrets and then permanently remove them I got the `Forbidden` error. I then went and modified the Access Policy to give my account the `Purge` permission on Secrets thinking this would allow me to permanently delete the Secrets. However, even after giving my account `Purge` permissions I am still getting the `Forbidden` error when trying to permanently remove Secrets that are in  `InRemovedState`.

Answer (score 3):

If you just enable `Soft-Delete`, the `Purge` permission is enough. But if you also enable `Purge-Protection`, you need to wait for the retention days to delete the secret permanently, no matter what permissions you got.

Reference - [Purge protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-soft-delete#purge-protection) and [Permitted purge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-soft-delete#permitted-purge).

> Exceptions are:
>
> - When the `--enable-purge-protection` flag is enabled on the vault itself. In this case, Key Vault will wait for 90 days from when the original secret object was marked for deletion to permanently delete the object.

By default, the retention period is 90 days, if it is necessary, you could set it  from 7 to 90 via powershell. (The doc says once it is set and saved it cannot be changed, actually it can, just use the powershell)

```
$r = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -ResourceType Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults -Name <keyvault-name>
$r.Properties.softDeleteRetentionInDays = "7"
$r | Set-AzResource -Force
```

[image]

Comment: Access to the property `softDeleteRetentionInDays` must have been removed because it is not a property exposed on my Key Vault.

Comment: @phydeauxman What is your meaning? You mean you could not find the `Retention period (days)` in the keyvault -> Properties in the portal? That is the `softDeleteRetentionInDays`.

Comment: @phydeauxman Or you mean the powershell script not work, you could not set the `softDeleteRetentionInDays`? If so, what is the error?

Comment: when I grab the Key Vault into a variable, there is no `softDeleteRetentionInDays` property under `$r.properties`

Comment: @phydeauxman Could you find it in the portal? See my previous comment.

Comment: yes...but it is grayed out so I can modify it from the default 90 days

Comment: @phydeauxman Yes, my keyvault is also grayed out, try the command again, make sure you are using it correctly, it should work.

Comment: the property is not there...not sure what to tell you

Comment: @phydeauxman If it is existing in the portal, the `softDeleteRetentionInDays` is must existing, I am sure you are using the incorrect keyvault name or group name, or you are using the incorrect subscription. You can use resource explorer https://resources.azure.com/ to find the keyvault, https://i.stack.imgur.com/wR2JH.png